# Starting a new activity from ViewPager and going back to the same page

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

In my app there is a viewpager with 3 fragments in it.
In one of the fragments I'm starting another activity.
I want the user to go back to the same viewpager page he were in before on back/up.

I implemented it successfully using the activity that hosts the viewpager's `onPause` and `onResume` methods. It worked but the problem was that `onResume` was being fired after `onCreate`, which resulted in the app starting at the same page (instead of a "default", different page I set in the `onCreate` method).

I then tried to place the `onResume` code in the launching activity's `onOptionsItemSelected` method, but that didn't work at all.

**Launched activity:**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

        vpPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int value = vpPref.getInt("viewPagerPage", -1);
        if (value != -1) {
            MainActivity.instance.mPager.setCurrentItem(value);
            vpPrefEditor = vpPref.edit();
            vpPrefEditor.remove("viewPagerPage");
            vpPrefEditor.commit();
        }   

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Main Activity: (hosts the viewpager)**

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    vpPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    vpPrefEditor = vpPref.edit();
    vpPrefEditor.putInt("viewPagerPage", mPager.getCurrentItem());

    vpPrefEditor.commit();
}
```

The problem is in the first code. I don't know whether this is a placement problem or getting the wrong instance of `MainActivity` that is wrong...

**What could be the cause to this behavior?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bad way of accessing the `ViewPager` from `MainActivity`(I hope `MainActivity.instance` isn't a static field holding a reference to a `MainActivity` instance). You should let the `MainActivity` completely handle the `ViewPager`'s position:

In the `onPause()` of the `MainActivity` you would keep the current code. In the `onResume()` method of the `MainActivity` you would have:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    vpPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    final int value = vpPref.getInt("viewPagerPage");
    final boolean shouldRestore = vp.getboolean("restoreStatusFlag");
    // we are again in the MainActivity so also make 
    // restoreStatusFlag  as false in the preferences
    if (shouldRestore) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(value);  
    }
}
```

The `shouldRestore` preference would be set from the launched activity in the `onCreate`. This way if `MainActivity` is started you'll keep the default page(`shouldRestore` will be false as the launched activity didn't run yet). If after `MainActivity` you go to the launched activity `shouldRestore` will become `true`(you need to set it in the `onCreate`) and as you come back the `ViewPager` will be set to the right page in `onResume()`.

This leaves one scenario where the user could go to the launched activity(the `shouldRestore` will be true) but never comes back to `MainActivity` with BACK. For this you could test the category from the `Intent` that started `MainActivity`(which I'm assuming is the one mentioned in the manifest as the launcher activity):

```
Set<String> catg = getIntent().getCategories();
for (String cat : catg) {
     if (cat.equals(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)) {
        // reset the shouldRestore flag to false so we end up with the default page 
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - thanks a lot! By the way, is there another, better way to access an instance of `MainActivity`? or is it not a good practice at all? I know it's possible inside a fragment using `getActivity()`, and broadcasters/receivers for different activities.

Comment: @xTCx Better way to access the MainActivity from outside of it(like another activity?). If yes, then this is to be avoided because once an `Activity` calls `onPause()`, that activity could get killed by the system so trying to access it in another activity would bring problems.